# JQuery alias to register event once per element + handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Using `element.off('event', handler).on('event', handler)` insures that an event is only registered once per **element** + **handler** combination.

Is there an alias in JQuery that provides the same functionality via 1 function?

*-not to be confused with `.one`, which invokes, not registers it only once!-*

**Edit:** Now I have to declare the handler by reference before I am able to use it as such, which creates a lot of extra code.

**Conclusion:** I fixed this issue by implementing a `once` function myself:

> $.fn.once = function() {    return this.off.apply(this,
>   arguments).on.apply(this, arguments); };

Comment: you know that the `.off()` and `.on()` functions are from jQuery?

Comment: he ideally wants to do that using a call to a *single* function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, jQuery doesn't have a built-in mechanism for preventing your adding the same handler more than once to an element. Your workaround is one way (provided `handler` really is the **same** function that was registered earlier), another is a marker class (don't add the handler if the class is there, then add the class and handler at the same time), or marker `data` property (same), etc.

(It's kind of amusing, because the DOM *does* automatically filter out adding the exact same function for the same event on the same element. But since jQuery manages its own list of handlers so it can ensure activation order across browser vendors, do event namespacing, and similar, the DOM's mechanism doesn't kick in.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `bind` & `unbind` methods to make this happen.

You can register an event only once, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').bind('click', function(e) {
    alert('Only works for 1st time');
    $(this).unbind();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! However, in your example, I want the handler to be executed every time I click. When I register the handler a second time, I do not want the handler to be executed twice.